# Make an event where that detects if a boolean becomes true to display a message

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a GUI application that works with printers connected via USB. What I've got now is the code to detect whenever a printer was connected to the computer. But what I'm trying to achieve is a simple tray message that displays only when someone plugs the printer.

So far, I was using [QTimer](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QTimer.html?highlight=qtimer#PySide.QtCore.QTimer), but the problem is that when the printer is still plug the message keeps appearing and that's not what I'm looking to do. With **setSingleShot** set in **True**, it does appear once but if I unplug it and plug it again the message won't appear.

What I'm basically looking for is a sort of time-based event but that's constantly checking, like on the OS that whenever you plug your printer it shows a status message only once, not every X seconds. Is there any other type of event I should try to get the result I want?

**EDIT:** Here's the code that detects the device:

```
import re, subprocess

DEVICE_RE = re.compile(".+ID\s(?P<id>\w+:\w+)")
# ...
def lsusb():
    # A python version of the command 'lsusb' that returns a list of connected usbids
    df = subprocess.check_output("lsusb", shell=True).decode('utf-8')
    devices = []
    for line in df.split('\n'):
        info = DEVICE_RE.match(line)
        if info:
            dinfo = info.groupdict()
            devices.append(dinfo['id'])
    return devices
# ...
def detect():
   usbs = lsusb()
   if '0a5f:000a' in usbs:
       return True
```

Comment: Could you please explain how you detect that a device is connected (pseudo code should be fine). It looks (from the basic information you provided) that some easy state machine should do the trick.

Comment: @OnWhenReady I just added the code.

Comment: Use [pyudev](https://pyudev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - it has built-in support for pyside/pyqt.

Comment: @ekhumoro I already have the code working, and what pyudev does is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @LeandroPoblet. Amongst many other things, it has support for [monitoring pluggable devices](https://pyudev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide.html#monitoring-devices). How is that different from what you want to do?

Comment: @ekhumoro Because it does the same thing my code does with far more functions I do not need, I need a basic, rudimentary implementation of the code, which is what I achieved with my code. Second, the pyside integration is only a trigger which is something I already solved like I mentioned in my code, the only problem I'm having is to make this trigger show a pop-up, which I will have to do anyways and pyudev only provides another signal, which I have to wrap to do anything, so I'm back on square one.

Comment: Maybe I'm not making it clear enough, so I'll try to summarize it: I want to know which event I need to use to do the following:

Plug device -> show pop-up once.
Unplug device -> do nothing.
Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @LeandroPoblet. There are no such events in Qt. You need a third-party library like pyudev for that. But if you don't want to use one of those, you will have to poll the devices yourself. It sounds like you may be doing something like that already. However, since you haven't posted all of the relevant code (i.e. the pyside parts), it's impossible to say why it's not working as expected. It would help if you posted a small, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a statemachine.

- state no Printer
- state Printer detected
- state Printer active

With your QTimer you regularely check if lsusb finds the printer.
If found, you change to detected, open the popup and change to state active.
In state active you regularely check if the Printer still can be found. If not you change back into state no Printer.

Comment: if you need further assist let me know. PySide offers the infrastructure for statemachines. https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QStateMachine.html